# Animations not working when entering (Tailwind, TransitionGroup, Typescript)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, tailwind-css, react-transition-group

I've created a wrapper component to supply a list of class names via a string to support Tailwind utility transitions.  This is intended to be nested in a TransitionGroup component to support animations of multiple items, like a list.

I'm able to animate out just fine, but entering is not working.  Can you help me spot the bug in this code, please?

react 16.13.1
react-transition-group 4.4.1

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/delicate-feather-ymozq

(logging in there to watch the div reference in case the classes weren't being applied, but they seem to work fine)

```
import React, { ReactNode } from "react";
import { Transition as ReactTransition } from "react-transition-group";

interface TransitionProps {
  in?: boolean;
  timeout: number;
  enter?: string;
  enterFrom?: string;
  enterTo?: string;
  leave?: string;
  leaveFrom?: string;
  leaveTo?: string;
  children: ReactNode;
}

export function CSSTransition(props: TransitionProps) {
  const { enter, enterFrom, enterTo, leave, leaveFrom, leaveTo } = props;
  const nodeRef = React.useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

  const enterClasses = splitClasses(enter);
  const enterFromClasses = splitClasses(enterFrom);
  const enterToClasses = splitClasses(enterTo);
  const leaveClasses = splitClasses(leave);
  const leaveFromClasses = splitClasses(leaveFrom);
  const leaveToClasses = splitClasses(leaveTo);

  function splitClasses(string: string | undefined): string[] {
    if (string) return string.split(" ").filter((s) => s.length);
    return [];
  }

  function addClasses(classes: string[]) {
    nodeRef.current?.classList.add(...classes);
  }

  function removeClasses(classes: string[]) {
    nodeRef.current?.classList.remove(...classes);
  }

  return (
    <ReactTransition
      in={props.in}
      nodeRef={nodeRef}
      timeout={props.timeout}
      unmountOnExit
      onEnter={() => {
        console.log("onEnter", nodeRef);
        addClasses([...enterClasses, ...enterFromClasses]);
      }}
      onEntering={() => {
        console.log("onEntering", nodeRef);
        removeClasses(enterFromClasses);
        addClasses(enterToClasses);
      }}
      onEntered={() => {
        console.log("onEntered", nodeRef);
        removeClasses([...enterToClasses, ...enterClasses]);
      }}
      onExit={() => {
        console.log("onExit", nodeRef);
        addClasses([...leaveClasses, ...leaveFromClasses]);
      }}
      onExiting={() => {
        console.log("onExiting", nodeRef);
        removeClasses(leaveFromClasses);
        addClasses(leaveToClasses);
      }}
      onExited={() => {
        console.log("onExited", nodeRef);
        removeClasses([...leaveToClasses, ...leaveClasses]);
      }}
    >
      <div ref={nodeRef}>{props.children}</div>
    </ReactTransition>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hope this will help you in some way : https://codesandbox.io/s/g6gd5?file=/src/index.js:924-928

Comment: Thanks!  Will dive in tonight.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Solution:

In `CSSTransition.tsx`, change

```js
import { Transition as ReactTransition } from "react-transition-group";
```

to

```
import { CSSTransition as ReactTransition } from "react-transition-group";
```

### Explanation:

Tailwind class names rely on CSS animations.

`Transition` isn't designed to work with CSS animations as the `onEnter` and `onEntering` methods are called so quickly that a DOM repaint (a frame of the animation) doesn't occur between them. Thus, all the classes you set for `enterTo` are immediately applied without any chance to transition to them.

`CSS Transition` on the other hand, adds an `-enter` class as it creates the element, then adds an `-enter-active` **on the next tick/frame**. Finally, after the timeout, it removes all classes except for adding in a `-done` class.

The transition between the `-enter` and `-enter-active` class is the key to allowing CSS transitions to take place. One tick/frame is added between those classes which allows the library to force a repaint. This repaint forces the `onEntering` classes to transition as intended to the `onEntered` classes.

In other words, `Transition` switches to the `enterTo` state immediately whereas `CSSTransition` gives one frame between the class switch which is needed to allow the animation to take place.

The DOM usually animates/changes at a maximum of 60 frames per second (depending on the implementation/end-user screen refresh rate) leaving 16ms for each frame; it doesn't care about what happens between between those 16ms. If the final state after class changes is your `enterTo` state rather than your `enterFrom` state, it will ignore the `enterFrom` state and thus never show you the Tailwind animations.

#### Sources:

- [React Transition Groups Docs](http://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/transition/)
- [React Transition Group Repaint Code](https://github.com/reactjs/react-transition-group/blob/5007303e729a74be66a21c3e2205e4916821524b/src/CSSTransition.js#L208-L215)
- [Example of what a Tailwind class adds](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/transition-timing-function/#app)

Comment: Of course, it's something this simple.  Of course!  Thank you so much.  It's stumped me for days but in the process, I did learn a lot about how react-transition-group works.  It works like a charm now.